# How do I get the Russian tanks?

Tags: war-thunder

I started playing with the Germans, but I would like to play the Russians.

The game says I have to play 9 games.

What kind of games is the game referring to? Do I have to win the games or can I leave the game early?

Comment: I've only watched my other half play this briefly on the ps4 but I would assume you had to play (and complete) the games win or lose, I wouldn't have thought leaving early would count.

Comment: It means you have to click the "to battle" button 9 times and finish the games 9 times. no specifics

Answer (score 1):

You need to play 9 games all the way through. I'm not 100% certain but I don't think it counts toward the games if you leave early. You could always give it a shot though :P

Answer (score 1):

When you start WT, you can choose your first nation. You have to make some progress to unlock other nations. It is the same with airplanes. 
By the game, it means matches.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if they wanted you to just start and leave, what would be the point of making you play 9 games? You probably have to complete the 9 games